# How to Fetch Subreddit videos and stream them on my website

Tags: reactjs, api, reddit

I am creating something like instagram reels but the posts come from all videos of a  subreddit.
I already created the  that shows the Videos and the swipe to next functionality.
But How do i fetch videos from specific subreddits and stream it in that ?
Am using React JS framework.

Comment: All i need is the HTML and Javascript that fetch the video url and show it in the div.

Comment: You should probably use their API?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.